# Grab the last x objects from an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I am trying to grab the last x numbers of objects in an array and store it in another array.

Like this it works:

```
    NSMutableArray *LastLines = [[LogLines subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [LogLines count])] mutableCopy];
```

However this does not:

```
NSMutableArray *LastLines = [[LogLines subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(([LogLines count]-4), [LogLines count])] mutableCopy];
```

and the following error shows up in the log:

2013-03-13 15:00:43.475 [38565:303] *** -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: range {83255, 83259} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 83258]

However the range seems like it should fall within the bounds so I am not sure why it is giving this error.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `NSArray -subarrayWithRange:` method as other answers suggested, **BUT** beware if the range exceeds the array count (e.g. getting last 10 line while array only contains 4 elements), it will raise an exception!

To avoid this, simply use an `if` to check the array count first...

```
NSArray *logs = <some long array>
int lastLogsCount = 100;
if (logs.count > lastLogsCount) { // check count first to avoid exception
    logs = [logs subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(logs.count - lastLogsCount, lastLogsCount)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one shouldn't work either. Arrays are zero-based, so calling an array's `count` method will always return one more than the last index that is used. If you change your code to

```
NSMutableArray *LastLines = [[LogLines subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(([LogLines count]-4), 4)] mutableCopy];
```

it should work. I am not sure why the first line does work, though.

Comment: When I do that I get the following error:

2013-03-13 15:48:27.112 [38764:303] *** -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: range {86699, 86702} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 86702]

The range seems viable, but still returns extends beyond bounds.

Comment: I figured it out. I misunderstood that the second value on range is an incremental value from the first value, the following works:

NSMutableArray *LastLines = [[LogLines subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(LogLines.count - 5, 4)] mutableCopy];

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, your array has 10 items, `count` takes you to position 10. As such an array starts from position zero and extends to position 9, position 10 will be 1 beyond bounds.

Take one away from count to get the last position:

```
NSMutableArray *LastLines = [[LogLines subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(([LogLines count]-4), [LogLines count]-1)] mutableCopy];
```